# Etymology of "im Freien"

Tags: etymology

While studying the various usages of [*im* in Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/im/), I came across this usage of *im* with the following grammatical note:

> während eines bestimmten Vorgangs; dabei seiend, etwas zu tun
>
> nicht auflösbar; bildet mit dem substantivierten Infinitiv [und »sein«] die Verlaufsform

The two examples given made good sense to the definition

> Dieser Schauspieler ist im Kommen.
>
> Der Junge ist noch im Wachsen.

However, when I looked around in Google for more examples and came across *im Freien* meaning *outdoors*, I found out that the verb *freien* seems to be an outdated usage for "to marry or to court a lady". Have I found a wrong example of the Duden scenario here? The only way I think it could work if "courting" was very tightly linked with being outdoors, a bit like in Bollywood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a particularly good example of a not well known pun.

`im Freien` has indeed two different meaning:

1. *outdoors* (where one is generally free=`frei`)
2. *whily marrying/courting* with the very explanation you give. But this meaning is extraordinary. Usually, no one would think of this meaning.

So the sentence

> Im Freien bin ich glücklich.

Might equally suit a pioneer and Casanova.

Comment: Your comment on the pun put a smile on my face since it is very apt to my current situation.  When I was "courting" my wife we used to hike a lot.  Now with our 2 year old, I no longer have exclusive access to the missus.  So indeed "Im Freien bin ich glücklich."!

Answer (score 3):

In the expression "im Freien" you have the adjective frei. It has nothing to do with the verb freien or the noun Freier which describe a special relationship between man and woman. Frei (adj) and freien belong to different word families.

Answer (score 1):

Duden is correct: *im Fahren* (while driving), *im Vorbeigehen* (in passing), *im Fallen* (while falling).

*Im Freien* is just a special case, so Google is also correct; *im Freien* means outdoors, as opposed to *im Haus*. See also [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=im%20freien&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&sectHdr=on).

*Freien* as a Verb (and the matching noun *Freier*) do refer to courting a woman. *Freien* is old style, *Freier* is mostly used for men visiting prostitutes.